# Finding $ \int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

I have no idea what substitution should I make here, a hint will be greatly appreciated.

$$ \int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}dx $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hint:

$$ \int \frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}dx \\ =\frac{1}{4e}\int \frac{(z-1)e^{z}}{z^2}dz$$ Put $z=2x+1$.
Now note that $$\int \frac{(z-1)e^{z}}{z^2}dz \\ =\int\frac{e^z}{z}dz- \int\frac{e^z}{z^2}dz\\=\left[\frac{e^z}{z}+ \int\frac{e^z}{z^2}dz\right]- \int\frac{e^z}{z^2}dz \\=\frac{e^z}{z}+C(\text{integral constant})$$

Comment: Did you miss the $x$ in the integral. Using your substitution we get $\frac{1}{4e}\int \frac{(z-1)e^z}{z^2} dz$

Comment: @pondy: YES. You are right. I will edit it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try making use of this property 
$\displaystyle  \int  e^{ax} (f'(x) + a f(x)) dx = f(x) e^{ax} + c $ and $\displaystyle  f(x) = \frac{1}{2x+1} $

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, it looks like integration by parts (which I generally prefer to avoid) might actually solve this problem rather cleanly.

$$u=xe^{2x},du=2xe^{2x}+e^{2x}dx=(2x+1)e^{2x}dx$$
$$dv=(2x+1)^{-2}dx,v=-\frac12(2x+1)^{-1}$$
$$\int\frac{xe^{2x}}{(2x+1)^2}=-\frac{xe^{2x}}{4x+2}+\int\frac12e^{2x}dx=$$
$$-\frac{xe^{2x}}{4x+2}+\frac14e^{2x}+C$$

Comment: I think you should put brackets around $2xe^{2x}+e^{2x}$  on the first line.